# R + PostgreSQL - IN operator

Tags: r, postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL in R and try to use the IN operator but it doesn't work.
All the connections are working (also the object con is specified, the problem is in the query).

I have the following code.

```
COLUMNS <- function(){c("A","B","C")}
DEALS <- function(){c("DealA","DealB","DealC")}
TABLE <- "TABLE_NAME"

QUERY_DEALS <- sqlQuery(con, paste(
"SELECT", paste0("\"", COLUMNS(),"\"",sep="",collapse=","),
"FROM", TABLE,
"WHERE \"dealname\" IN ", paste0("\"",DEALS(),sep="",collapse=",")))
```

It returns the following error.

```
42601 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near ""DealA"";
Error while executing the query
```

I am expecting the columns (from the COLUMNS function) from the deals specified in the DEALS function. Could anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Best regards, Robert

Comment: Did you forget a `"` in `WHERE \d`? If it was a typo, your resultant SQL query string doesn't have the values after `IN` wrapped in parentheses: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

Comment: It was a typo. I changed it now.

    "WHERE \"dealname\" IN", paste0... is the correct one.

Comment: Then all you need to do is add the parenthesis as I suggested and linked to.

Comment: Correct! Thanks for pointing this out, was staring blind on it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT", paste0("\"", COLUMNS(),"\"",sep="",collapse=","),
"FROM", TABLE,
"WHERE \"dealname\" IN (", paste0("\"",DEALS(),sep="",collapse=","),")"))
```

Is the correct answer as @hrbrmstr pointed out.

Comment: FWIW You should really avoid writing queries this way. Too hard to read. `sprintf` is your friend.